# words other than "performance" to describe a player's outcome?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expression-choice

I am writing a post based on various sports players and their performances, and would like to know which alternative words or phrases can be used instead of repeating the word "performance".

For Example:-

Describing the first player -"his performance was outstanding in the previous season".

Describing the second player - "due to his performance in the previous season"

I have tried to find the synonyms for the word but most of them give a non-sporty impression.As there are many player's the repetition of the word in each description is decreasing the quality of post.

Comment: How about "rating" and "ranking".

Comment: efficiency? velocity? productivity? - but they also non-sporty
U can say "he showed outstanding results ..."

Comment: What type of player?  My first thought was _portrayal_ but then I realized you might not be referring to players on a stage giving a performance...

Comment: Did you discount using stats?

Comment: Positive: excellence, scores, success, successes, triumphs, feats. Negative: mediocrity, shortcomings. Neutral: outcomes, play, “due to his previous season.”

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the noun **play**, which in sports is a commonly-used substitute for *performance*.

Your examples:

> Describing the first player -"his **play** was outstanding in the previous season".
>
> Describing the second player - "due to his **play** in the previous season"

As used here, you can think of **play** as meaning the same thing as *quality of play*.

From Lexico:

> **[play](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/play)**: the action or manner of engaging in a sport or game.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential routes I could recommend in approaching this problem. There are synonyms to performance that you could use, like ability, that would procure a similar effect and make your writing less repetitive. The second route, however, would be to simply become more specific in what ways the player you are trying to describe performed. For instance, if you are a football coach, you could say something about your quarterback like: "this player's quick decision making led to key strategic successes." Small, specific praises will give your players not only a boost to their self-esteem, but a tangible guide to improving as a player.

Comment: I liked the second route, but it is very hard to believe that there is no alternative word in English language for "performance" when used in sports context.

Comment: You could say conduct, execution, ability, proficiency, capability, effort, or skill in place of "performance" in the sentence "due to his performance in the previous season" and achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use sport technical expressions like "his shooting accuracy, his goaling score, his ball control skills" or something like that.